# Passing variables to powershell script block in a jenkins pipeline

Tags: powershell, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Is there a way to use groovy variables inside a powershell script? My sample script is as following..

```
  node {
  stage('Invoke Installation') {
  def stdoutpowershell
  def serverName = env.fqdn
  withEnv(['serverName =  $serverName']) {
      echo "serverName : $serverName"
      stdoutpowershell = powershell returnStdout: true, script: '''
          write-output "Server is $env:serverName"
      '''
  }
  }
```

Comment: `$envserverName` -> `$env:serverName`

Comment: @BenH it looks like I made a small mistake while creating sample code block. It should be as you mentioned so I have updated the script but the problem here is not that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot interpolate variables in single quotes or triple-single quotes. Use triple-double-quotes:

```
  stdoutpowershell = powershell returnStdout: true, script: """
      write-output "Server is $env:serverName"
  """
```

Comment: Is there any way to have more then one statement inside , like whole powershell script block  loke ~~~   stdoutpowershell = powershell returnStdout: true, script: """
      write-output "Server is $envserverName" write-output "serevelkjl" 
  """ ```

Answer (score 1):

There are two options for passing variables.

- Env export variable
- local variable

Add the complete script, see the below.

```
node {
    stage('Invoke Installation') {
        def stdoutpowershell
        def serverName = "env.fqdn"
        
        // Use Env export variable
        withEnv(["SERVER_NAME=$serverName"]) {
            stdoutpowershell = powershell returnStdout: true, script: '''
                write-output "Server is $env:SERVER_NAME"
            '''
        }
        println stdoutpowershell
        
        // Use local variable
        stdoutpowershell = powershell returnStdout: true, script: """
            write-output "Server is ${serverName}"
        """
        println stdoutpowershell
 
    } 
}
```